# Does the LibreOffice 5.2 snap use my existing profile?

Tags: libreoffice, snap

I came across [LibreOffice 5.2.0 beta2 as a snap package](https://skyfromme.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/libreoffice-5-2-0-beta2-as-a-snap-package/).

If I install it, will it use my existing profile in `~/.config/libreoffice/4/user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently. As snap packages will be containerized in the end, it is unlikely to do in the future -- at least not in this simple a way. We will need a solution for profile migrations and not reinstalling extensions for each update. After all snap will enable up- and downgrading and parallel installations of different version of a software.

Comment: I got it going. There are a variety of messages in the terminal. It appears to use the Adwaita theme. None of the changes in Tools > Options are saved. The clipboard contents are no longer lost on closing LibreOffice and that's nice.